# Block of text in HTML

Tags: html

Stupid question but I don't really know how to google this. Is there a html tag that will let you delete all its text in just one key press? I'm trying to add a textarea (i.e. {{DefaultValue}}) in my html on button click and I want to program it so that when the user clicks delete, it will delete the whole text, not one text at a time.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want it to empty the textarea or delete the textarea?

Comment: You should indicate whether javascript is acceptable, as an HTML-only solution would yield much different answers from what has been suggested so far. For example, I don't let websites run any javascript by default, and you may want to make it easier for users like myself to use your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be done with scripting; you'll need to listen to keypresses on a regular input (or a contenteditable element). When the delete key is pressed (identified by its code), you'll simply wipe out the contents of the element.

For example:

```js
$("[data-delete").on("keyup", function ( event ) {
    if ( event.which === 8 ) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8hbXz/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using `javascript`(maybe use [onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)), but I don't think there is such html element. Moreover it is more up to your browser how to handle keypresses in a given element so behavior may vary in different browesers.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: user html5 placeholder

```
<input name="foo" placeholder="Search" />
```

Solution 2: clean it with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearThis(target){
        if (target.value == 'Search')
            target.value= "";
    }
</script>
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="clearThis(this)" />
```

Comment: Be cautious with the second approach; once the content has user-defined values, it will still be cleared when focused. This deviates from the behavior we've come to expect with the placeholder attribute.

Comment: That's typically how people polyfill the placeholder attribute.